# How to remove all but last 10 files

Tags: shell, files, ls, rm, xargs

I accumulate sequentially named files as the result of an automated process, and I would like to keep only the last 10 around. I tried this, which had the effect of deleting everything:

`ls -r | more +11 | xargs rm`

Apparently piping `more +n` causes the entire result to be piped, without regard to the `+n` argument.

What would be the correct approach?

Comment: by 'last' do you mean oldest? Newest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll admit,
nothing in the `more` documentation jumps out at me as saying that this will happen. 
But, since you want to start displaying (outputting / processing) the input (list of files)
at a specified line number (specifically, 11), the logical command to use is `tail`:

```
ls -r | tail -n +11 | …
```

A word to the wise: test things like this by piping into `cat` or `xargs` (with no command)
before you do something dangerous like `xargs rm`.

Comment: That worked! Must be a quirk of `more`.